# Redirect the URL request using apache mod-jk

Tags: apache2.4, mod-jk

I have the Apache Web server with the below config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 111.111.111.111
    ServerAlias hostname

    # Following prevents hotlinking
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ [NC]
    RewriteCond expr "! %{HTTP_REFERER} -strmatch '*://%{HTTP_HOST}/*'"
    RewriteRule ^.*$  / [R,L]
    ...
    ...
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I need to redirect all the requests with suffix /v1 to the same path without containing the 'v1' suffix.
example: https://example.com/v1 to https://example.com

How can I achieve ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using a `RedirectMatch` this way:

```
RedirectMatch ^/v1$ / [R,L]
RedirectMatch ^(.*)(/v1)$ $1 [R,L]
```

So https://example.com/v1 would result in https://example.com and 
for example https://example.com/something/v1 will be redirected to https://example.com/something

Comment: Yeah Thanks for the answer. I need like below. https://example.com/v1/something to be redirected to https://example.com/something and process the request and the response url should again be like https://example.com/v1/something